# How do I get to the Minecraft Launching Terminal?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I play Minecraft on a Mac and was wondering how to get to the Minecraft Launching Terminal, because my Minecraft keeps crashing at the Launch screen without it. I am hoping that after I get to the launching terminal, I can input a certain code (found it on a different website and it worked for a lot of people) and it will work. All I need to know is how to get to the Minecraft Launch terminal.

Answer (score 3):

It's not the Minecraft Launching Terminal, it's a program that comes with your Mac called Terminal. Use the search bar of any Finder window or the search feature of the Launch Pad to search for "terminal".

Comment: Or you can search for it in the launch pad

Comment: @ModDL New-fangled widgets and gizmos! In my day we walked uphill both ways to the search bar and ... ;) But yes, that's a useful alternative. :)

Answer (score 1):

When Minecraft stops loading at the end of the loading screen, this is often caused by malware or adware - for example, like PremierOpinion